# how to deploy a private github repo to a GCE cluster

Tags: github, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

I'm trying to deploy my app to a google compute engine cluster.  I followed the [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/tree/master/7-gce/gce) which sets up the cluster and creates a start script for each vm instance.

The example start script doesn't use github though.

What I would like to do is have the start script check out the project from my private github repo (if it's not already there).

I have created a deployment ssh key which I've added to my git repo's "Deploy keys".

The problems I have are:

- how to I distribute this deployment key to each machine in the cluster?
- what commands do I add the the start script so that the git clone works without any prompts?

Answer (score 1):

Read this [adding-removing-ssh-keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys?hl=en#block-project-keys) to setup project-wide public SSH keys from a Linux instance.

First, To allow project-wide public SSH keys, set the metadata value to FALSE

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME] --metadata block-project-ssh-keys=FALSE
```

In the command prompt, use the compute instances add-metadata command to set the instance-only ssh-key value. Include the --metadata-from-file flag and specify the path to the public key file list that you made.

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME] --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=[LIST_PATH]
```

For your second question: [Non interactive git clone (ssh fingerprint prompt)](https://serverfault.com/questions/447028/non-interactive-git-clone-ssh-fingerprint-prompt)

Comment: Thanks.  I see a warning "Private key(s) are detected. Note that only public keys should be added".  I've created a "deployment key" for my github repo.  I need to add that private key to each machine in the cluster.

Comment: Oh , I misunderstanding you question. If you want to deploy app to each machine in your cluster , you better have something like Jenkins to deploy your code to each machine by scp. So you only need one machine have your private key. Another way is what you want to distribute you private key to each machine so that they can  from github ( not good) . But you can try to use sensible to do it .

Comment: Thanks.  I'm deploying my (encrypted) private key to each machine at the moment.  It works but doesn't feel like a good solution.  I assumed, maybe incorrectly that this was a solved problem.  Maybe not.  But surely deploying the a google compute engine cluster direct from a private github repo can't be such a weird thing to do.